# log4j is not working on solaris 10

Tags: log4j, weblogic, solaris, soa

I am creating a **SOA** application in which i configured **log4j**. I deployed the application on **windows** , then log4j is working fine, log file is creating on the specified file as well as log is printing on console. But when i deployed the same application on **Solaris** neither log file is generated nor logs are generated on console. And i not getting any warning or error. I am putting log4j.properties file in classpath.

I am stuck in this problem since last three days, but not getting any resolution.

I am using the following configuration

1) **log4j-1.2.17.jar**
2) **weblogic 10.3.6.0**

Your help will be very helpful.

Thanx
Ankur jain

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin console and check the servers setting regarding logs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Cris for reply,

My prob has resolved, there was a little mistake that i have done.

I had put log4j.jar in weblogic domain lib as well as application lib. when i delete the jar from weblogic domain lib and restarted the server. Log file had generated.

Thanx
Ankur jain